# simulation in R w.r.t 8 numbers

Tags: r

I have 8 numbers

```
IniValue=c('3%','3.2%','3.6%','4%','4.2%','4.2%','4.5%','4.5%')
```

how should I generate 50 numbers `~(0,0.1%)` with respect to each of them and make them a matrix

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do - what do you mean by `~(0,0.1%) with respect to each of them `?

Comment: for example, in IniValue, I would like to do a simulation with respect to the 8 numbers. and generate 50 random numbers with mean =0 ,sd=0.1%. and get a 8*50 matrix

Comment: 3% + e, where e follows mean=0, sd=0.1% distribution

Comment: So you mean if `a` is a number from `IniValue`, you want to simulate from `~N(a, (0.1)^2)` ?

Comment: sorry for my expression, mean=0, (0,0.1%) for each number

Comment: That's what i wrote, if `X~N(mu,sigma^2)` then `a+X~N(a+mu,sigma^2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do

```
IniValue=c(3,3.2,3.6,4,4.2,4.2,4.5,4.5)
random <- matrix(0, nrow = 50, ncol = length(IniValue))
for (i in 1:length(IniValue))
{
     random[,i] = rnorm(50, mean = IniValue / 100, sd = 0.1/100)
}
```

Comment: sims not defined. sorry for my followup question

Comment: oh yea, I figure them out.  thank you soooooooo much